# Synge & Schild Exercise 1.2

Tags: geometry, tensors

$x^1 = a \cos u^1 \\
x^2 = a \sin u^1 \cos u^2 \\
x^3 = a \sin u^1 \sin u^2 \cos u^3 \\
\vdots \\
x^{N-1} = a \sin u^1 \sin u^2 \sin u^3 \cdots \sin u^{N-2} \cos u^{N-1} \\
\displaystyle x^N = a \prod_1^{N-1} \sin u^i
$

My pattern recognition skills are decent enough that I can tell this is a hypersphere. But, **why?**

---

Specifically if I call the pattern `c`, `sc`, `ssc`, `sssc`, `...`, `ssssssssssssssssc`, `sssssssssssssssss`, then a few aspects of the sequence seem strange:

- First of all why does `s` appear so much more often than `c` in the formula? (**edit:** it's clear now  these are interchangeable)
- Doesn't a product of $\sin$es often end up smaller than a single $\cos$ine? Since $|\sin \theta| \leq 1$ So where's the symmetry of the sphere there?
- Apparently I never thought hard enough when I was learning azimuthal angles in the first place. Why do some of the terms get just one trig function whilst others get products of trig functions?
- Lastly it would seem more "balanced" to have a pattern like `scscscscsc` than `sssssssssc`.

Comment: Should $x^3$ be $sin sin cos$ instead of $sin cos cos$?

Comment: Is it me or the third line should be $x^3 = a \sin u^1 \sin u^2 \cos u^3$?

Comment: David H(ilbert?), we are connected :)

Comment: Yes, thanks @DavidH, that was a typo.

Comment: Thanks @Pipicito your correction was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll describe the idea that allows a rigorous proof by recurrence.

Let's take this sum (I'll put indices in subscripts for clarity):

$$\frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 $$
and study it's two last terms: 
$$\cos^2 u_{N-1}   \prod_1^{N-2} \sin u^2_i + \sin u^2_{N-1}\prod_1^{N-2} \sin u^2_i$$
$$=\prod_1^{N-2} \sin u^2_i.$$

Now we combine this term with the $(N-2)$-th element of the sum to further reduce the number of factors. After repeating this step $N-2$ times we obtain that the total sum is equal to $1$.

Comment: Great, thanks. That makes perfect sense.